# Where can I find a correlation matrix between the revenues of different industries?

Tags: data, market-data, historical-data

I don't need something super complicated, I would just like a quick and dirty way of estimating the correlation coefficients between the revenues of different companies. Information on companies in the world as a whole would be desirable but is not necessary.

Answer (score 4):

I found US data [here](http://www.bea.gov/industry/gdpbyind_data.htm). While this data doesn't include correlations, these can be calculated relatively easily from this data.

Answer (score 0):

[Sageworks](https://cfo.sageworks.com/) has the data you'll need and will allow you run these correlations within their software.

Answer (score 0):

You can get individual company revenue and industry classification on Quantopian. You could then calculate the correlations. The data comes from Morningstar as described here: https://www.quantopian.com/posts/fundamental-data-from-morningstar-now-available-for-backtesting

(disclosure: I'm the ceo of quantopian).